# Could not load a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please verify your Appium installation

Tags: node.js, appium, appium-ios, wdio-v4

I'm using appium command by npm as global and I am working in a wdio project with appium as a depedency.

**package.json**

```
...
"appium": "^1.17.1",
"wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
"wdio-cucumber-framework": "^0.3.1",
"webdriverio": "^4.8.0"
...
```

Project's environment is using Node v8.16.0

I used to use Appium 1.16.1 and everything was well.

**capabilities**:

```
{
  appiumVersion: '1.17.1',
  deviceName: 'iPhone 11',
  platformName: 'iOS',
  deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
  platformVersion: '13.1',
  app: ***.app.zip,
  automationName: 'XCUITest',
  newCommandTimeout: 480,
  fullReset: false
}
```

I recently update Appium to 1.17.1 (both global command and local dependency) and running the tests I started to get this error:

```
ERROR: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not load a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please verify your Appium installation
iphone11.ios.13_2.app_zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [appium-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor) to verify if your environment is properly setup and meets Appium requirements for each platform.

Install it:

```
npm install appium-doctor -g
```

Use it:

```
appium-doctor --ios
```

It will show what exactly is missing.

Comment: hi! Thanks for your answer.. I had run that command but only got warns.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if appium installation is corrupted, so it cannot dynamically load the appium-xcuitest-driver package. Try to reinstall the server or try on another machine
I was also facing same issue, after **reinstalling Appium** desktop resolved this issue temporary. It occurred even after reinstalling.

In that case I installed appium server using npm.
Open terminal
I assumed, you have appium means you already have node installed on your machine

Hit command `npm install -g appium`

Hit `appium` on using that appium server. It is not giving me any error while execution

Answer (score 0):

just reinstall appium and you're good to go